# Random Forest Regression Prediction scale

Tags: random-forest, data-transformation, quantiles, feature-scaling

I am training a random forest regressor with $y_{train}$ and $X_{train}$ both quantile transformed (makes them in 0 to 1 and uniformly distributed) and scaled (stretch them to be in -1 to +1). When my $y_{train}$is in the range -1 to +1 my $ \hat{y}_{test}$ is in a narrower range eg. -0.03 to 0.03 (both referred in quantile and stretched space). Inverse quantile transforming from this makes it a miserable output.

Although this is just an example I have observed similar results for decision trees as well as linear regression, that $\hat{y}$ predicted are in narrower range. Is there a way to handle this ?

a. How to make $ \hat{y}_{test \ or \ train}$  to be in range of my realized/actual target variable ?

b. Are there any common techniques used to handle this ?

Comment: Why do you use this strange feature scaling? Any references/links? Generally, forests and trees do not need such transformations ...

Comment: Agree to the point that Tree models would not need such scaling. Motivation for scaling was to take out fat tails/outliers at least for linear regression. My query is still centered on how to get the y_hat  predicted in the same range as the trained y even on before the inverse quantile.

Comment: In place of linear regression maybe quantile regression?